# how to ensure proper indentation in datas ifstreamed from a file. Look at my code , it's not giving desired results

Tags: c++, c++11

```
if(role==2)
    {
        int arr;
        ifstream record("total.txt");
        record>>arr;
        record.close();
        string names[arr];
        int age[arr];
        ifstream file("names.txt");
        ifstream file0("ages.txt");
        for(int i=0;i<arr;i++)
        {
            getline(file, names[i]);
            file0>>age[i];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<arr;i++)
        {
            cout<<names[i]<< " "<<age[i]<<endl;

        }
    }
```

Here I am having 2 files contaning names and ages of some person. File names total.txt contains a number which is total number of persons. Flies named names.txt and ages.txt contains names and ages one in each row.

```
ages.txt:                names.txt:
18                       anil kumar
25                       naman ojha
27                       vishnu pandit
52                       sangakara g
48                       helen keller
```

I got the result of my above written code as:

```
anil kumar 18
naman ojha 25
vishnu pandit 27
sangakara g 52
helen keller 48
```

results which I wanted :

```
anil kumar                      18
naman ojha                      25
vishnu pandit                   27
sangakara g                     52
helen keller                    48
```

How to achive this result? New ideas are welcomed.

Comment: See `setw` or `iostream.set_width`.  This will set the *field width* in spaces.  Also search your favorite C++ reference for "left justify" and "right justify".

Comment: No need for "new" ideas, just research existing ones ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`left`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/left) IO manipulators:

```
for(int i=0;i<arr;i++)
{
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(32)
        << names[i] << " " << age[i] << std::endl;
}
```

`left` ensures the following data is aligned to left, meaning any fill characters will be appended after the output data. `setw` set width of the following data output. If the formatted data is shorter than this amount, the excess is filled with fill characters, which is space by default. If the formatted output is equal or longer than the field width, no fill characters are appended. After data formatting is complete, width is reset to 0, which means the following data output will not be extended to the previously specified width. In the above, "data" means the object that is inserted into the stream immediately after the IO manipulator - `names[i]` in the code above.

In order to guarantee proper column alignment for any input, you may also want to loop over the `names` array to find the maximum length of the name strings and use that as the field width.

```
int max_width = 0;
for(int i=0;i<arr;i++)
{
    if (names[i].size() > max_width)
        max_width = names[i].size();
}

for(int i=0;i<arr;i++)
{
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(max_width)
        << names[i] << " " << age[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Or use [`max_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/max_element), something like `int max_width = std::max_element(names.begin(), names.end(), [](const string &l, const string &r) { return l.size() < r.size(); })->size();`, assuming `names` is not empty.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Yeah, but that doesn't really make the code simpler.